# How to backup email messages with sender name, email id and body?

Tags: android

I want to backup all emails that received in inbox of my android mobile.

I have some basic knowledge of BackUp Manager. Can you guide me, how to go about backing up emails with sender name, email id and body using the BackupManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer

```
            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this); 
            Log.e(TAG,"Error"+AccountManager.get(this));
            Account account = getAccount(accountManager);

            if (account != null) {
              Log.d(TAG,"Account"+account.name);

            }

            Cursor c = null; Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.email.provider/account");
            String RECORD_ID = "_id";
            String[] ID_PROJECTION = new String[] {RECORD_ID };
            c = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI,ID_PROJECTION,null, null, null);
            Log.d(TAG,"Response"+c);
```